# Perl/mysql floating point imprecision

Tags: mysql, perl, floating-point

I'm using Perl to communicate floating point numbers with a mysql database. I perform a multiplication in perl:

```
 $var = 0.001 * 3;
```

I then store this value in a  mysql database in a column of type DOUBLE. I later retrieve the result, perform a further multiplication and addition to the number and store it back into the database

```
$previous_result_from_db += 0.001*1 + 0.001*0.5.
```

The result stored in the database should be **0.0045**, but instead I get: **0.0045000000000000005**. I'm trying to understand where the source of the imprecision is. Is it Perl or the database? What is the correct way to handle this kind of floating point interaction to avoid the imprecision?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard response: [`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  It's neither perl or the database.  It's floating point arithmetic.

Comment: " What is the correct way to handle this kind of floating point interaction to avoid the imprecision?" — Corrolary response to the preceding: Use fixed-point.

Comment: @Miller, there's also a less dense explanation: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "10.0 times 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0" -- Brian Kernighan, The Elements of Programming Style

It is a known limitation of FLOAT and DOUBLE that they are *imprecise numeric* data types. This is built into the design of the IEEE 754 format. It affects all programming languages that store floating-point numbers using this format.

MySQL documents this in this appendix: [B.5.5.8 Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html).

PHP documents this in [Warning: Floating point precision](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.float.php).

If you want a scaled numeric data type in MySQL that avoids this rounding behavior, use [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Comment: Thanks Bill, DECIMAL seems right since they're monetary values. While your answer doesn't comment on the Perl side of things, your comment above included a link to handling this issue in Perl, so I'm going to accept it as solving my issue. Here's the link: http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/perl/